# How to setup custom (first level) domain on Basic Azure machine?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I see that I can more or less easily create a custom second level domain aka
contoso.cloudapp.net on Azure VM.
But I would like to setup a real domain I purchased such a contoso.com without the clouapp.net.

Is that even possible with a Azure VM? Or do I need to purchase something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use cname for you new domain to the cloudapp domain .

You can use an alias too . And there is a faq step by step to do that with azure gui or powershell tools .

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/

Comment: Are there extra fees for that? I didn't spot out anything.

Comment: No added fees if you do that on your dns domain .